# Is it possible to filter products in the admin catalog by Category in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, filter

Is it possible to filter products by category in Magento 2 under Catalog?

So when I go in the admin to catalog, can I filter the product list according to the category / categories the products are assigned to?

Comment: By "under catalog", do you mean  you need category filter in admin product grid?

Comment: Yes, exactly so I can choose only products under specific category.

Comment: For this you have to add category column in the product grid programmatically.

Comment: How would I do that? Custom theme for admin?

Comment: theme won't do that , you have to write your own code

Comment: try this extension it may work , https://github.com/DRAJI/Categoryfilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can simply call block and get product collection using below code :**

> Block File :

```
<?php
namespace Company\Categories\Block;

class Categoryproduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCategoryProduct($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $category;
    }
}
```

> phtml File :

```
$cat_Id = 10;
$getProudctcollection = $block->getCategoryProduct($cat_Id);

<ul class="category-products">  
                        <?php 
                                foreach ($getProudctcollection as $product) : ?>
                                    <li class="level0-child">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                            <?php echo $product->getName();?>
                                        </a>
                                    </li> 
                        <?php   endforeach;?>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Happy to help you sir ... @Kaki Sami ... !! Happy Coding :)